# register_post_type sort order by title by default

Tags: custom-post-types, sort

If I add a custom post type (example code below), in the admin page for the new custom post type the posts are sorted by ID by default.  Is there a way to set the default sort order to the post title instead (only for this new custom post type)?

```
    $labels = array(
    'name' => 'States',
    'singular_name' => 'State',
    'add_new' => __( 'Add State' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New State' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit State' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New State'),
    'view' => __( 'View State'),
    'view_item' => __( 'View State'),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search States'),
    'not_found' => __( 'No States found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No States found in trash' ),
    'parent' => __( 'Parent State')
);

$args = array('public' => true, 
              'show_ui' => true,
              'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
              'show_in_menu' => true,
              'labels' => $labels,
              'supports' => array( 'title','editor')
              );
register_post_type( 'states', $args );
```

Answer (score 11):

You could force the order via [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

```
function wpa_order_states( $query ){
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'edit' == $screen->base
    && 'states' == $screen->post_type
    && !isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ){
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_order_states' );
```

Comment: Note that if you set `$_GET['orderby']` and `$_GET['order']` instead of directly modifying the query the column header arrow is displayed properly.

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer was better [here](http://www.dansmart.co.uk/2011/09/how-to-order-your-custom-post-type-edit-screen-by-menu-order/) (altered to suit question):

```
function se91124_order_post_type($query) {
  if($query->is_admin) {

        if ($query->get('post_type') == 'States')
        {
          $query->set('orderby', 'title');
          $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        }
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'se91124_order_post_type');
```

Please note that **se91124_order_post_type** can be changed to any function name, **States** is the post_type name or label, the orderby **title** can be anything you like (e.g. menu_order), and obviously **ASC** can be changed for DESC.

Original from URL:

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {

  if($query->is_admin) {

        if ($query->get('post_type') == 'portfolio')
        {
          $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
          $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        }
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```